# Random letters showing in Powershell script error making it so hard to find where the error stems from

Tags: powershell, shell, windows-registry, windows-11, regedit

I keep receiving random letters Powershell script error.

I made a changing mouse scheme script based on system OS theme. I keep receiving random letters as shown in the image below when running the Powershell script:

[image: script error]

This is my script:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$daySegment2,  # 0 = Day, 1 = Night
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][int]$daySegment4,  # -1 = N/A, 0 = Sunrise, 1 = Day, 2 = Sunset, 3 = Night
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][bool]$nightMode,   # True if night mode is enabled
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$imagePath # Path to current wallpaper image
)

$Location = "~\AppData\Local\WinDynamicDesktop\scripts\globalScripts\NightValue.xml"
$PreviousNightValue = Import-CliXml $Location

$Location2 = "~\AppData\Local\WinDynamicDesktop\scripts\globalScripts\StartValue.xml"
$StartValue = Import-CliXml $Location2

$NightValue = If ($nightMode) {1} Else {$daySegment2}

if ( ($NightValue -eq 0 -and $StartValue -eq 1) -or ($NightValue -ne $PreviousNightValue -and $StartValue -eq 0 -and $NightValue -eq 0))
{
$RegConnect = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]”CurrentUser”,”$env:COMPUTERNAME”)
$RegCursors = $RegConnect.OpenSubKey(“Control Panel\Cursors”,$true)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“”,”W11 Cursor Light HD v2.2 by Jepri Creations”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“AppStarting”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\working.ani”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Arrow”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\pointer.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Crosshair”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\precision.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Hand”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\link.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Help”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\help.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“IBeam”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\beam.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“No”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\unavailable.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“NWPen”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\handwriting.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Person”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\person.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Pin”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\pin.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“precisionhair”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\precision.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeAll”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\move.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNESW”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\dgn2.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNS”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\vert.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNWSE”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\dgn1.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeWE”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\horz.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“UpArrow”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\alternate.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Wait”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_light_v2.2\busy.ani”)
$RegCursors.Close()
$RegConnect.Close()
$CSharpSig = @’
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
             uint uiAction,
             uint uiParam,
             uint pvParam,
             uint fWinIni);
‘@
$CursorRefresh = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSig -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo –PassThru
$CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo(0x0057,0,$null,0)
}
ElseIf (($NightValue -eq 1 -and $StartValue -eq 1) -or ($NightValue -ne $PreviousNightValue -and $StartValue -eq 0 -and $NightValue -eq 1))
{
$RegConnect = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]”CurrentUser”,”$env:COMPUTERNAME”)
$RegCursors = $RegConnect.OpenSubKey(“Control Panel\Cursors”,$true)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“”,”W11 Cursors Dark HD v2.2 by Jepri Creations”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“AppStarting”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\working.ani”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Arrow”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\pointer.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Crosshair”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\precision.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Hand”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\link.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Help”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\help.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“IBeam”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\beam.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“No”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\unavailable.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“NWPen”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\handwriting.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Person”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\person.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Pin”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\pin.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“precisionhair”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\precision.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeAll”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\move.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNESW”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\dgn2.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNS”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\vert.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeNWSE”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\dgn1.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“SizeWE”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\horz.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“UpArrow”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\alternate.cur”)
$RegCursors.SetValue(“Wait”,”%SYSTEMROOT%\Cursors\W11_dark_v2.2\busy.ani”)
$RegCursors.Close()
$RegConnect.Close()
$CSharpSig = @’
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
                uint uiAction,
                uint uiParam,
                uint pvParam,
                uint fWinIni);
‘@
$CursorRefresh = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $CSharpSig -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo –PassThru
$CursorRefresh::SystemParametersInfo(0x0057,0,$null,0)
}

$StartValue = 0
if (($NightValue -ne $PreviousNightValue))
{
    $NightValue | Export-Clixml -path $Location
}

if ($StartValue -ne 0)
{
    $StartValue | Export-Clixml -path $Location2
}
```

I tried removing some parts of the script, I think the problem stems for registry editing. But had no luck. the error kept showing no matter what I delete.
I tried putting the
$PSStyle.OutputRendering='PlainText'
at the top of my script, I received the same error.
I tried setting the NO_COLOR to 1 inside my script. Did not fix the issue.
I don't have access to the application that runs the script, I just can edit my script.
BTW, that's started happening when the software started using PowerShell 7 instead of windows PowerShell(V5) I started getting this error.

Comment: These "random" letters look very non-random. They look like [ANSI escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33206814/10765659). I'm not sure where they come from, I'm not a Windows guy. It may be the error message itself was designed to be displayed in a terminal that understand escape sequences, but it got to a simple error window somehow. Can you try to run the script in a modern terminal, observe the (or an) error message there. Alternatively (but unlikely) the sequences are in your script. How do you edit the script? Just in case make sure your editor does not hide anything from you.

Comment: there is no error running the script in POWERSHELL ISE

Comment: That is because the PowerShell ISE will auto-load libraries for form/GUI level-called stuff (which you are doing in your code). In the powershell/pwsh consoles, you must explicitly load them first.

Answer (score 0):

... removing the form/GUI stuff.

Also of note here in the BOM setting in WinPS and PS Core.
BOM is a default in PSCore, not in WinPS. You have to set it.

You can make a registry change in Windows to force the BOM setting always in WinPS. Yet, you need to be aware of other impacts when doing that.

***Update***

I just re-read your last statement in your first post. The PSCore part.

PSCore is using .Net Core. WinPS is using Full .Net. You are potentially using things that are not part of .Net Core. It's only available in Full .Net.

.Net Core is not fully backward compatible with WinPS because of the framework differences.

WinPS is part of every Windows System. PSCore, is a separate standalone, side-by-Side installation. If you have WinPS-bound stuff, do not try to do that in PSCore.

You can use the #Requires statement at the top of your code to alert folks, that they must run your stuff in WinPS not PSCore.

> about_Requires Prevents a script from running without the required
> elements.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-7.3
>
> .NET vs. .NET Framework for server apps
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server
>
> What is .NET? Introduction and overview
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/introduction
>
> What are the Differences Between .NET Framework & .NET Core?
>
> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/difference-between-net-framework-and-net-core/
>
> .NET and .NET Core Support Policy
>
> https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: this did not work. I put all the lines above my script I kept receiving the same error